# How can I reference system assembly in Cake script?

Tags: cakebuild

I want to use `System.Data` in my cake script, to perform some DB operations.

My script is sth like this:

```
#r "System.Data"

void DoSomething()
{
    System.Data.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlConnection(..);
}
```

However, this does not compile resulting in error
`error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

What is the proper way to reference System assemblies (from GAC) in Cake scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.Data is already loaded with cake.
Your problem is the namespace of SqlConnection.
The correct NS is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

your file can just have this

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
void DoSomething()
{
    SqlConnection conn = null;
}
```

Comment: That's obviously true. Being used to Intellisense for the whole life make you crippled when you don't have one ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use intellisense as well if you are using vs code.

Go to Extensions and add Cake Extension.
Then open command pallete and select Add tool from Nuget.
and just Type Cake.Bakery and install it.
Run the build script once and restart the vs code again.

You will get intellisense. Not to worry.